# XML Schema Validation Error. It appears to be inline with the schema

Tags: xml, web-services, amazon-web-services, xsd, json-schema-validator

I am getting an error while validating my xml document against its schema. Please help.

Below is the XML document I am trying to validate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QuestionForm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
  <Overview>
    <Text>This is overview</Text>
  </Overview>
  <Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>nextmove</QuestionIdentifier>
    <DisplayName>Display Name</DisplayName>
    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
    <QuestionContent>
      <Text>The Main Question will go here?</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
      <FreeTextAnswer>
        <Constraints>
          <IsNumeric minValue="0" maxValue="9999" />
          <Length minLength="0" maxLength="4" />
        </Constraints>
        <NumberOfLinesSuggestion>1</NumberOfLinesSuggestion>
      </FreeTextAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
```

[Here is the link for XML Schema document.](http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd)

Here is the error message

> Unhandled Exception: Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Exceptions.ParseErrorException: There was an error parsing the XML question or answer data in your request.  Pl
>       ease make sure the data is well-formed and validates against the appropriate schema. Details: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element
>       'QuestionContent'. One of '{"http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd":QuestionIdentifier}' is expected. (14084243
>       91173 s)
>          at Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.MTurkClient.ProcessErrors(ErrorsError[] errors, Object ret, OperationRequest opsReq)
>          at Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.MTurkClient.SendRequest(Object req)
>          at   Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.MTurkClient.CreateHIT(CreateHITRequest request)

```
  [1]: http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you show does not have the error indicated.  It's valid against the schema you point to.

Either you are submitting input to the validator which is not the input you show, or the validator is using some schema other than the one you point to.  Either way, the only solution to your problem is to make sure that the validator is actually using the inputs you want it to use, and not some other inputs.

Comment: You are awesome. I was not passing the right input structure to the method.